# Is there a way to check the error log in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there a way to output an error log from spark streaming? The error log looks ambiguous.

```
StreamingQueryException: Writing job aborted.

=== Streaming Query ===

Identifier: [id = 6bc7f9c4-b8da-4cbf-8525-2ff720343ed2, runId = 6b70373f-7e9a-470d-96d5-e62aef9b91a2]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[topic-name]]: {"topic-name":{"0":950}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[topic-name]]: {"topic-name":{"0":6120479}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
...
```

Comment: You can try to check spark ui

Comment: You can check yarn logs (command: yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID>) if your application is running under yarn.